# TypeError: dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am studying NLP and trying to make a model for classifying sentences.  I am creating my class with a model but I get an error saying that the input should be of type Tensor, not tuple. I use 4.21.2 transformers version.

```py
class BertClassificationModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, bert_model_name, num_labels, dropout=0.1):
        super(BertClassificationModel, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_model_name, return_dict=False)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(768, num_labels)
        self.num_labels = num_labels
    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, token_type_ids=None):
        pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)
        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)
        return logits
```

`TypeError: dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple`

Comment: Are you able to return `pooled_output` and comment out the lines below it? You need to look at the `pooled_output` object at the two places you are defining it. At some point you have a tuple. Probably a tuple of tensor. Get `BertClassificationModel.forward` to return `pooled_output` and look at the type and try indexing it.

Comment: Also, you should try to post everything to recreate the code. What are the dims of the tensor you are inputting to this model? You should have `torch.rand(dim1, dim2)` with the dims of what you are feeding the model so we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you face, is that the output of `self.bert` is not a tensor but a tuple:

```py
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification, BertTokenizer

bert_model_name = "bert-base-cased"
t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(bert_model_name)
m = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_model_name, return_dict=False)

o=m(**t("test test", return_tensors="pt"))

print(type(o))
```

Output:

```
tuple
```

I personally do not recommend using `return_dict=False` as the code becomes more difficult to read. But changing this parameter doesn't help in your case, as you want to use the pooler output which is removed by the classification head of [BertForSequenceClassification](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertForSequenceClassification) (the output of BertForSequenceClassification is listed [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.21.2/en/main_classes/output#transformers.modeling_outputs.SequenceClassifierOutput)).

You already wrote in your own answer, that you don't intend to use the classification head of BertForSequenceClassification and you can therefore load BertModel directly (instead of initializing `BertForSequenceClassification` and only using BERT as you did with: `BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_model_name, return_dict=True).bert`):

```py
from torch import nn
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer

class BertClassificationModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, bert_model_name, num_labels, dropout=0.1):
        super(BertClassificationModel, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(bert_model_name)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(768, num_labels)
        self.num_labels = num_labels
    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, token_type_ids=None):
        pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids).pooler_output
        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)
        return logits


m = BertClassificationModel("bert-base-cased",4, 0.1)
o = m(**t("test test", return_tensors="pt"))
print(o.shape)
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([1, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I wanted to add my own classification layers, but when i get `BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained` the output model already get this layers. In order to add yourself classification layers should get `BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_model_name, return_dict=True).bert` This returns clear model. As a result, my class looks like this:

```
class BertClassificationModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, bert_model_name, num_labels, dropout=0.1):
        super(BertClassificationModel, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(bert_model_name, return_dict=True).bert
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(768, num_labels)
        self.num_labels = num_labels
    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, token_type_ids=None):
        pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids)['pooler_output']
        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)
        return logits
```